# Wordpress excerpt - image and text

Tags: wordpress

This is the mockup I have:

<del>http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/3172/featuresb.jpg</del>

Each section will be an excerpt of a post that has a certain tag.

Is there any way of doing this so a client doesnt have to touch and  tags or code like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the content with your own function.

Instead of using `<?php the_content() ?>` its better to use this: `<?php your_function(get_the_content()) ?>`

The function can be put on functions.php and you are free to code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the_content` filter like so,

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter'); // 
function my_content_filter($content) {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_excerpt == ''){ // check if the post has excerpt
        $content = strip_tags($content);  //strip tags
        $cont_array = explode(' ',$content);
        if(count($cont_array) > 55)  //number of words wanted in excerpt default is 55
        $content = implode(' ',array_slice($cont_array, 0, 55)).'...';
        $content = '<p>'.$content.'</p>';
    }else{
        $content = $post->post_excerpt; //copy excerpt to content
    }
    return $content; //return content
}
```

The above code checks if the post has excerpt, if it has excerpt it returns excerpt else returns first 55 words (default length for excerpt).

Answer (score 0):

use this code for limit the post content.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php substr($post->post_content, 0, 12); ?> ...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your themes functions.php file:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} 
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
```

then add this this in your loop:

```
<?php print '<p>'.excerpt(40).'</p>'; ?>
```